# Систаксис пространств имен xml

Tags: xml

Изучаю стандарт gs1. Мануал содержит пример xml - объясните тупому, что за синтаксис:

```
<epcis:EPCISDocument
 xmlns:epcis="urn:epcglobal:epcis:xsd:1"
 schemaVersion="1.1" creationDate="2015-04-14T09:05:08.720-04:00">
 <EPCISBody>
 <EventList>
 <ObjectEvent>
 <eventTime>2012-09-23T05:10:12.000Z</eventTime>
 <eventTimeZoneOffset>-05:00</eventTimeZoneOffset>
 <epcList>
 <epc>urn:epc:id:sgtin:0614141.112345.12345</epc>
 </epcList>
 <action>ADD</action>
 <bizStep>urn:epcglobal:cbv:bizstep:receiving</bizStep>
 <disposition>urn:epcglobal:cbv:disp:in_progress</disposition>
```

Собственно вопрос к xmlns:epcis="urn:epcglobal:epcis:xsd:1". Почему только первый тэг предваряется epcis: ? Я бы понял если бы каждый тег предварялся epcis: или если было бы написано xmlns="urn:epcglobal:epcis:xsd:1". Судя по xsd все теги относятся к тому же пространству имен.  xsd: https://www.gs1.org/docs/epc/epcis_1_1-schema-20140520/EPCglobal-epcis-1_1.xsd

Туплю или ошибка в описании?

Comment: В схеме есть `xsd:any`. Возможно, именно под это описание попадают теги без неймспейса. Не уверен.

Comment: К сожаление нет. Эти теги описанны и обозначенный именно как urn:epcglobal:epcis:xsd:1

Comment: Да, в схеме есть описанные теги в пространстве имен. Но в схеме есть и `any` - этому тегу соответствует _любой_ тег, даже без неймспейса. Вероятно, приведенный вами xml попадает именно под этот случай.

Comment: Почти разобрался) Это связано с тем, что в начале схемы написано elementFormDefault="unqualified". Как я понял это означает что элементы не следует специфицироват схемой